# Change service data through the stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, here would be my app config:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
    .state("/", {
      // something ..
    })
    .state("/fail", {
      template: '<div class="panel"></div>',
      controller: "PageCtrl",
      resolve: {
        blah: function(SomeService)  {
           SomeService.item = "Changed!"
        }
      }
    });
```

I'd like to be able to set a variable on a service, and have it propagate to a controller. I've looked over the official documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider), and can't seem to make heads or tails of the specifications without a good example. I'm actually not even sure if resolve is what I should be using.

Note that I'm using $stateProvider from the ui.state module.

If this is confusing, I'll post more information tomorrow and probably a plnkr/jsfiddle example, but it's late and I need some sleep.

Thanks for any help.